# I can RDP into server but cannot browse using explorer

Tags: rdp, remote, explorer

Disclaimer: Networking is not my strong point, it is my Achilles' heel.

At work I have been given a sandbox server to test my software with, I have full control over the server itself but the network/domain it sits in is offlimits for me.

I can RDP into it just fine from my machine, but for whatever reason I CAN'T view anything in the server by opening up an explorer window and going to address "\server ip address\"

Is there some setting I need to turn off or on to allow browsing using explorer?

Any help will be appreciated, thanks in advanced!

**UPDATE :** The machine is NOT local, it is remote and the OS is Server 2008 R2.

Comment: are you an admin on the server?  if so try \\serverip\c$ what happens?

Comment: Yes I am, however they're two different domains and logins. I just tried and it did not connect or anything.

Comment: did you get a login prompt?

Comment: ok reread your statement so you are on (rdp) the local server and doing \\local server\c$ ?

Comment: What version of windows server? 2008 r2? 2012? older?

Comment: To answer your first question: no I didn't get a login prompt, instead I got the "Network Error Windows cannot access \\ip address\c$". To answer the second I am on rdp to it, and am trying to do \\ip address\c$. I should clarify that it is NOT a local server, I'm sure it's remote(overseas). It is Windows Server 2008 R2.

Comment: so the "ip address" is the ip address you rdp'd to?

Comment: try exactly this "\\localhost\c$".

Comment: Yes the ip address is the address I rpd's into. It's from my machine that I fail to browse from. Doing "\\localhost\c$" from INSIDE that machine work fine, however doing "\\ip address\c$" from MY machine doesn't work. Thanks for all this help by the way!

Comment: ok makes more sense then port 445 is probably blocked somewhere.

Comment: That's kind of what I'm looking for. I didn't know I needed port 445 open, is there anything else I need to do?

Comment: nope just unblock port 445.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this won't help the next person with this same issue resolve their issue, but I eventually turned the firewall off altogether on the remote machine and **still** I couldn't connect to it.

The only explanation I can come up with is that there's either a physical firewall or a firewall in some other component blocking that access at a higher level than my machine.

Comment: I'm quite sure you are being blocked by a fw somewhere, do this for a last ditch test if you can try this "telnet serverip 445"  what happens.  Not sure if you have telnet available but you have nothing to lose.

Comment: That was one of the first things I did when I started researching this. Couldn't connect. :(

Comment: guess your sandbox will be less useful then.

Answer (score 0):

Please explain a bit what you are trying to do.

Are you:

A) RDPing into server, and then trying to browse to other machines from within the RDP session?

B) Trying to browse to the server from your local machine while also RDPing into it?

Either way, I would check two things first. The firewall settings (netbios port 137-139) and the network adapter settings (is netbios enabled?).

Comment: more then likely ports 137,139 won't be involved in this conversation.